# Highlight other language word or letter in MS word file

Tags: applescript

I need to know can we make a apple script that can highlight other language  text or word or paragraph in the .docx file.

For example:

find English language word in German language docx file.

Googles kostenlose Online- Übersetzungsdienstsofort ihre Übersetzung von Text und Web-Seiten.

above is a German language text, here Google is english its should higlight Google.

Please suggest on this.

Comment: You could use the spelling dictionary. If it's set to German, won't the English words be found? You could also use a german word dictionary to check each word, but that seems hugely impractical. I have no good suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Yes i have tried by find and replace option in it by changing the language
but i need the english words highlightig.

Lets see wats can be done.